# Inno Setup: Installing service doesn't work on Windows XP

Tags: service, windows-services, windows-xp, inno-setup

I believe I have an error in creating a service in Windows XP Computers, because after my installation is finished I don't see any of my services installed.
This is how I create a service in my installer:

```
Filename: {sys}\sc.exe; Check: (IsAdminLoggedOn or IsPowerUserLoggedOn); Parameters: "create Example start= delayed-auto binPath= ""{app}\Example.exe"""; Flags: runhidden
```

This line works in all Windows besides Windows XP for some reason.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had tried your command on Windows XP command line, you would clearly see why it fails:

```
C:\>C:\WINDOWS\system32\sc.exe create Example start= delayed-auto binPath="C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"  
invalid start= field
...
```

Your `start=` parameter is invalid. You have to use one of the valid values:

```
 start= <boot|system|auto|demand|disabled>
```

The `delayed-auto` is supported since Windows Vista and newer only. You have to use a different start option on Windows XP.

If you want to use `delayed-auto` on Windows Vista and newer and another option on Windows XP, see [How to install a service with the delayed-auto startup type in Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35828041/850848).

Comment: I cannot use startup type demand because it would require the users to manually start the service. I edited my question so please take a look.

Comment: I moved my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35828041/how-to-install-a-service-with-the-delayed-auto-startup-type-in-winodws-xp